# Two different pronunciation of "понял"

Tags: выражения, произношение, лексикон

I just searched for phonetic of **понял** and found these:
**по́нял [пон’ил]**
**поня́л [пан’ал]**
Please let me know that both are correct? and have same meaning as **Got it!**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Поня́л** is a stress pattern pertaining to speech of grammarless native speakers, very low register.

Sometimes it can be used jokingly, with tongue in cheek, in informal conversations as a curt question **Поня́л?** or as a curt answer **Поня́л**, in which case it's a mockery.

Answer (score 8):

по́нял [пон’ил] is the only correct form use for either questioning and confirmation.

поня́л [пан’ал] is an informal form commonly used to question (the closest would be "do you get it?").
It's not so much of a mockery but pretty patronizing way which you wouldn't use with people you don't closely know as it has a condescending sounding to it.